# creating an object in java

Tags: java, android, object

i have a simple doubt in android programming. I am not familiar with java coding.so it might be a simple problem.

In the first two lines I am retrieving an array, which i passed from another activity to this activity...Then i am creating an array list . I am creating an object in the 4th line. Now comes the problem ...
I have to run a for loop to get the url value, which i have to pass it in the BaseFeedParser class. but i cant use the 4th line, i.e creating the object inside the loop because it will create a new object each time... which should not happen ... how can i fix this probelm?

```
                    Intent myintent = getIntent();
        String[] ActiveURL = myintent.getStringArrayExtra("URL");

        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser(url);

        // fetching all active URLs
        for (int i = 0; i < ActiveURL.length + 1; i++) {
            url = ActiveURL[i];
            messages.addAll(parser.parse());
        }

        // now getting the titles out of the messages for display
        for (Message msg : messages) {
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
        }
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: if you dont like to create basefeedParse object every time then you have to remove the constructor in BasefeedParser and then you can pass that URL to parser.parser(URL) method in XMLParser class, and you have to pass this from there to BasefeedParser some way by creating another method to assign value for the basefeedparser URL. but this may leads to Error also.

Comment: There is java convention that for variables start from lowercase. So change ActiveUrl to active Url. Actualy I dont understand your code... BaseFeedParser that I found in the Internet is an abstract class. And why you cannot create new Object ?

Comment: Java (and I suppose Android, too) has no principle problem with creating objects. A problem would only be if creating a BaseFeedParser is extraordinarily expensive, but I can't see why this should be the case. (I don't know the API, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems in your java code :

```
    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    //variables are named in camel case, starting with a lower case letter
    String[] activeURL = myintent.getStringArrayExtra("URL");

    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    //we will use parser later, see below
    //BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser(url);

    // fetching all active URLs
    //it's very easy to loop through a table in java / C / C++
    //learn the pattern, it's the simplest, you got confused with the final index
    for (int i = 0; i < activeURL.length ; i++) {
        //here you don't change the former object url was referencing,
        //you are saying that you give the name url to another object in the array
        //it doesn't create any new item, change giving them a name to use them
        url = activeURL[i];
        //create a new parser for each url, except if they can be recycled
        //i.e they have a property setUrl
        messages.addAll( new BaseFeedParser(url).parse());
    }

    // now getting the titles out of the messages for display
    for (Message msg : messages) {
        titles.add(msg.getTitle());
    }
```

Indeed, you could even shorten the whole thing by

```
    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    String[] activeURL = myintent.getStringArrayExtra("URL");
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    // fetching all active URLs
    //use a for each loop
    for ( String url : activeURL ) {
        //loop through messages parsed from feed to add titles
        for (Message msg : new BaseFeedParser(url).parse() ) {
           titles.add(msg.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

if you don't need the List of Message you called messages.

Comment: +1 for nice code .But this will make the app to Hang and show ANR dialog , because this will leads to for loop to access the network operation in UI thread itself so i recommend @ps00131 to use this code inside AsyncTask Or Threading Or Service.

Comment: @ps00131 if you like it you should consider accepting this answer so.